# flutter google places autocomplete List.builder pushing widget down

Tags: flutter

I am implementing google places autocomplete on flutter, but it pushes my bottom widget down. Is there a way to make sure that the places content overlays my bottom widget?

Below is my widget which has a textfield that houses the google autocomplete places section and two other below sections that contains additional widgets.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String _address = "";
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFeeedf2),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    //color: const Color(0xFFF4F6F0)
                    color: const Color(0xFFeeedf2)),
                padding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1, vertical: 5),
                child: Column(children: [
                  Form(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.location_city_rounded),
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide:
                            BorderSide(width: 3, color: Colors.grey),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                          ),
                          // icon: Icon(Icons.lock), //icon at head of input
                          //prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.people), //you can use prefixIcon property too.
                          labelText: "Search Property Locatio",
                          // suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye) //icon at tail of input
                        ),
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          print("hello2");
                          placeAutoComplete(value);
                        },
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  ListView.builder(
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: placePredictions.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(placePredictions[index].description!),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ]),
              ),
            ),
            const Gap(10),
            ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              children: [
                CarouselSlider(

                  options: CarouselOptions(
                    aspectRatio: 1.8,
                    viewportFraction: 0.9,
                    enlargeStrategy: CenterPageEnlargeStrategy.height,
                    enlargeCenterPage: true,
                    enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                  ),
                  items: CategoryModel.categories2
                      .map(
                          (category) => DetailedScreenCard(categoryModel: category))
                      .toList(),
                ),
              ],
            ),

            const Gap(25),
            Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                child: const DoubleTextWidget(
                    bigText: "Trending Properties", smallText: "")
            ),
            const Gap(10),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: 300,
                child:  FutureBuilder<List<ListingModel>>(
                  future: fetchData(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData){
                      List<ListingModel> list = snapshot.data!;
                      print("-------------");
                      print(snapshot.data);
                      return ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemCount: 5,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                            return Column(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                  child: ClipRRect(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                    child: Image.network("http://165.227.173.143/${json.decode(snapshot.data![index].images).cast<String>().toList()[1]}",
                                      height: 200,
                                      width: 300,
                                      fit:BoxFit.cover,),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, top: 0),
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      // Row(
                                      //   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      //   children: [
                                      //     Text(snapshot.data![index].type, style: Styles.headlineStyle1),
                                      //     Row(
                                      //       children: [
                                      //         const Icon(Icons.star_border_outlined),
                                      //         Text(" 4.99", style: Styles.headlineStyle3),
                                      //       ],
                                      //     ),
                                      //   ],
                                      // ),
                                      Text("${snapshot.data?[index].location}",
                                        style: Styles.headlineStyle3, textAlign: TextAlign.start,),
                                      const Gap(5),
                                      Text("K${snapshot.data?[index].cost}/Night",
                                        style: Styles.headlineStyle1.copyWith(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.blueGrey),),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            );
                          });

                      // return ListView.builder(
                      //     itemCount: list?.length,
                      //     itemBuilder: (context, index){
                      //       return Text(list![index].title);
                      //     });
                    } else {
                      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const Gap(20),
            //const Listing()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```